# css position:absolute problem

Tags: css

I have some css problem. here is what I need.

[image]

No matter how many words the title have(example: title could be `What's new today?`, could be `hello world`)

it always have a background line pass through the whole div, and the word's background is white. (the word should be `text-align:center;` and it's background looks like broken the line)

Here is my code:

```
<style> 
.ocell {
width:960px;
height:42px;
text-align:center;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.wd {
margin: 0 auto;
background-col: white;
margin-left: -10px;
padding: 5px;
}
.line {
position: absolute;
border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
margin-top:-18px;
width: 960px;
}
</style> 
<div class="ocell">
<div class="wd">Title</div>
<div class="line"></div>
</div>
```

also in http://jsfiddle.net/zApLA/  may be also can use a `background-image` instead of the line. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by simply using div with border-bottom for the line, and positioning element with text on that line. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s377S/).

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems with your CSS.

One - the .wd div spans the entire width of page (defaults to 100%)
Two - no z-index sset to say which div should be on top of which.

Try this code (worked in fiddle)

```
.ocell {
width:960px;
height:42px;
text-align:center;
padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
.wd {
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #f0f;
margin-left: -10px;
padding: 5px;
font-size:20px;
    z-index:10;
    border:1px solid #f0f;
    display:inline;
}
.line {
position: absolute;
border-bottom: solid 1px #999;
margin-top:-15px;
width: 960px;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Hmm you'll probably need to use conditional css then [link](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) to tweak it for IE. Our PC is being used for testing currently so cant help you there but try it out with coloured borders or backgrounds so you can clearly see what div is going where.